# .NET MAUI: Make Entry expand to multiple lines like an Editor but prevent newline on Enter

Tags: editor, maui, multiline

In a .NET MAUI application, I require a text input control that starts as a single-line input but automatically expands to multiline when the text exceeds the horizontal space. Additionally, this control should prevent users from manually entering a new line with the "Enter" key. The standard Entry doesn't auto-expand, and the Editor allows manual new lines. Thus, neither fits the requirement perfectly. I'm wondering if there's an existing workaround or if I need to resort to writing a custom handler.

Initially used an Entry for text input, anticipating that it would serve the need for single-line inputs without allowing users to add new lines using the "Enter" key. To accommodate situations where users input lengthy text, I wanted the Entry to automatically extend to the next line, similar to chat app behavior. I expected the Entry to grow in height when the text input reached the end of the available line space.

However, when I tried using the Editor, it didn't suit my needs because it allowed users to manually create a new line by pressing the "Enter" key.

Comment: Maybe Editor, with TextChanged event handler that removes newline. Be careful to avoid infinite recursion - altering text in TextChanged will fire another TextChanged event -- if there is no newline at end, return without doing anything.

Comment: You can try to add the [key down event](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjXvpHQs7iAAxUfS2wGHeLFBCcQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fuwp%2Fapi%2Fwindows.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown%3Fview%3Dwinrt-22621&usg=AOvVaw0YS0lptW-Qqog-TKppuWcT&opi=89978449) to the editor for the windows platform. But for the android, you can't detect the key down event from the soft keyboard.